# Reading a text file and showing only part of it some of it in python

Tags: python, python-3.3

So I'm creating a code in **python 3.3** where you have to guess a song with only the first letter of the song and artist so I formatted my text file like this:

```
Domo23-Tyler The Creator
Happy hour-The Housemartins
Charming Man-The Smiths
Toaster-Slowthai
Two time-Jack Stauber
etc...
```

So I was trying to work out a way to print this but only showing the first letter of each word in the song name and the whole artist name like this:

```
C M-The Smiths
```

Justwondering if anyone could help

Comment: Have a look into string slicing, and the `split()` function.

Comment: What code did your working out produce? Just so we can see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If your songs are stored let's say in "songs.txt" here is my solution:

```
import random

# Without the "with as" statement"
f = open("songs.txt", "r")
list_of_songs = []
text_of_songs = f.read()
#Closing the file - Thank you @destoralater
f.close()
for song in text_of_songs.split("\n"):
    list_of_songs.append(song)

def get_random_song_clue(list_of_songs):
    song = random.choice(list_of_songs)
    title, artis = song.split("-")
    title_clue = " ".join([letter[0] for letter in title.split(" ")])
    return f"{title_clue}-{artis}"

print(get_random_song_clue(list_of_songs))
```

**One random Output:**

```
D-Tyler The Creator
```

Comment: Hi I tried to implement that code but it says that "as" is invalid syntax

Comment: Hi, it wasn't necessary anyway it was just to make the code cleaner, I have been edited the code. But I thought it works in python 3.3.

Comment: @ViktorKelemen -- don't you need to call `f.close()` at some point?

Comment: It's not necessary but true, it is recommended you can call it right after the "text_of_songs = f.read()"  line the code works the same. I have been edited my code.

Comment: Rather than `f.read()`, the `with open('file') as f` convention should be used as this ensures the file handle is closed automatically, as not all Python implementations close file handles at gc.

Comment: @S3DEV I agree, but the question asker got "invalid syntax" on it.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, odd.  It definitely works in 2.7 as I tried it before commenting.  Possibly an implementation error on OP's part.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data is in a list, like so:

```
data = ["Domo23-Tyler The Creator",
    "Happy hour-The Housemartins",
    "Charming Man-The Smiths",
    "Toaster-Slowthai",
    "Two time-Jack Stauber"]
```

I'll build up the final code for you step by step.

1. Extract the song name by first splitting each data item at the "-", eg: `data[2].split("-")[0]`.
2. Split the song name at the spaces to get a list of the words in the song name: `data[2].split("-")[0].split(" ")`.
3. List comprehension to only keep the first letter of each word: `[word[0] for word in data[2].split("-")[0].split(" ")]`
4. Now concatenate that last list of letters: `" ".join([word[0] for word in data[2].split("-")[0].split(" ")])`
5. Add in the name of the artist: `" ".join([word[0] for word in data[2].split("-")[0].split(" ")]) + "-" + data[2].split("-")[1]`

Now finalise by doing the whole lot with another list comprehension. I've used a lambda function for cleanness.

```
hide_name = lambda song_record: \
                    " ".join([word[0] for word in song_record.split("-")[0].split(" ")]) \
                    + "-" + song_record.split("-")[1]

[hide_name(record) for record in data]
```

Output for the list given above:

```
['D-Tyler The Creator',
 'H h-The Housemartins',
 'C M-The Smiths',
 'T-Slowthai',
 'T t-Jack Stauber']
```

Edit: remember that this depends on your song records having precisely one "-" in them, which delimits the song name and artist. If either the song name or artist contains a hyphen, you'll get unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 78, in <module>
    + "-" + song_record.split("-")[1]
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'

Comment: @destoralater: oops, sorry. Fixed now. I had forgotten one of the line overflow markers `\` in the last code block. Should work now. Or just put it all on one line.